# Detectar quando há rotação de tela de tablet Windows

Tags: c#

Como faço para identificar quando houve uma rotação da tela do tablet Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [documentacao](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms812142.aspx) (infelizmente so em ingles) aqui:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
//. . .
//Set event handler
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int theScreenRectHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    int theScreenRectWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    //Compare height and width of screen and act accordingly.
    if (theScreenRectHeight > theScreenRectWidth)
    {
        // Run the application in portrait, as in:
    MessageBox.Text = "Run in portrait.";
    }
    else
    {
        // Run the application in landscape, as in:
        MessageBox.Text = "Run in landscape.";
    }
}
```

Esse metodo detecta se esta em landscape ou portrait.